# mongoose findOne work using id instead of _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was stuck for a while when I do `_id` in findOne function I got empty result.

```
exports.getUser = function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({id: req.params.id}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        msg: err
      })
    } else {
      return res.json({status:1, data: user})
    }
  })
}
```

Above code worked but I'm curious why this won't work

```
...
  User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, user) {
...
```

I think I have to parse req.params.id with ObjectId function, but is there any global method that ignore this rule? for me it make sense just use `_id: myId`

Comment: No, you don't have to parse your id. What doesn't work with your second code snippet?

Comment: Is it possible that there simply isn't any document in your collection with this _id? How did you create the document? And where did you get your _id from?

Comment: @Josh no, I checked my db, it's there, I couldn't get it using `_id`, but it worked with `id`

Comment: And your document doesn't have both an id and an _id field?

Comment: if you have declared field `id` separately then `id` is no longer equal to `_id`